# Why does this code produce a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

On line 18, I get a seg fault in the first iteration (i = 0).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char* str = "mono";

    int length = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; ; i++) {
        if (str[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        } else {
            length++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
        char temp = str[length - i - 1];
        str[length - i - 1] = str[i]; // line 18
        str[i] = temp;
    }

    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this algorithm to reverse a string.

Comment: Discussed endless times. `str[i] = temp;` writes to a string literal which is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for indicating which line is line 18.

Comment: Also you should learn about `strlen` and others in `string.h`

Answer (score 7):

You are modifying a string literal:

```
char* str = "mono";
```

and string literals are non-modifiable in C.

To fix your issue, use an an array initialized by the string literal:

```
char str[] = "mono";
```

Comment: I tried that before asking and I still got the same error. Let me try again.

Comment: Weird. It works this time. Thanks.

Comment: Nit: attempting to modify a string literal results in **undefined behavior**; this is not *quite* the same thing as string literals being *non-modifiable* (not all platforms will put string literals in a read-only data segment).  You should definitely treat string literals *as if* they are non-modifiable, though.

Comment: @JohnBode Also nitpicking: terminology in K&R2:  *"Strings are no longer modifiable"*, terminology in C99 Rationale: *"String literals are not required to be modifiable"* and terminology"* and terminology in C89 Rationale: *"Strings literals are specified to be unmodifiable"*

Comment: @ouah: yet neither the C99 nor C2011 standards documents themselves explicitly say that (at least, not that I've been able to find); they only say that "[i]f the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undeﬁned."  Both point out that writable string literals are a common extension (appendix J.5.5).

Comment: @JohnBode Well in C99, 6.2.5.6p15, a string literal is presented and it is written *"[...] has static storage duration and has type array of char, but need not be modifiable;"* which is the same wordings as in C99 Rationale *""String literals are not required to be modifiable"*".

Answer (score 1):

**Runtime Error:**

```
char* str = "mono"; // str points to an address in the code-section, which is a Read-Only section
str[1] = 'x';       // Illegal memory access violation
```

**Compilation Error:**

```
const char* str = "mono"; // This is a correct declaration, which will prevent the runtime error above
str[1] = 'x';             // The compiler will not allow this
```

**All Good:**

```
char str[] = "mono"; // str points to an address in the stack or the data-section, which are both Read-Write sections
str[1] = 'x';        // Works OK
```

**Notes:**

1. In all cases, a string "mono" is placed in the code-section of the program.
2. In the last example, the contents of that string are copied into the `str` array.
3. In the last example, the `str` array is located in the stack if `str` is a non-static local variable, and in the data-section of the program otherwise.